# How to add a query parameter for all requests in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

How can I put query params into all requests in spring webflux avoiding code duplication in all places where I open http connection?

I try to make a configuration for a WebClient bean with a filter that should put a query param in URL every time when I do http call but I cannot find a way how to do it. Is it possible?

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class IConnectionConfiguration {

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(@Autowired ExchangeFilterFunction tokenFilter) {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url)
                .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(tokenFilter);
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExchangeFilterFunction tokenFilter() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            //todo put token into request as a query param
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }

}
```

Api calls layer:

```
@Service
public class Client {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient client;

    //todo test method
    public void testConnection() {
        String s = client.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder ->
                        uriBuilder.path("/something/{val}/something")
                              //todo line which I'm trying to avoid
                              //.queryParam("token", "token_value")
                                .build("123-test"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an older question, this is the solution I went with myself in the end:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                        .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
                            req -> 
                                Mono.just(ClientRequest.from(req).url(
                                    UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(req.url())
                                        .queryParam("apiKey", "...")
                                        .build(true)
                                        .toUri()
                            ).build()))
                        )
                        .build();
```

This has the following advantages (depending on use case):

- It is applied on *all* requests, whereas the answers using `UriBuilderFactory` does not work when supplying a new uri template such as when using `webClient.get().uri(String uri, Function <UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction)`
- It uses `UriComponentsBuilder` for a cleaner way of modifying the URI.

Note that as per its documentation, `UriComponentsBuilder` created from an existing URI stores query params in `raw` form, which means that they are already fully encoded. Any new parameters added must also be added in fully encoded form, and in the end `build(true)` must be called with the `true` arguments to avoid double encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility that does not require overriding or using filter: Use `UriComponentsBuilder` with the query parameter that should be used for all requests. This instance of `UriComponentsBuilder` can than be used to instantiate a `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` for the `WebClient`.

Based on the code of the question:

```
public class IConnectionConfiguration {

    private static final String TOKEN_QUERY_PARAMETER = "TOKEN";

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(uriComponentsBuilder());
        return WebClient.builder()
                .uriBuilderFactory(defaultUriBuilderFactory)
                .build();
    }

    private UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder() {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam(TOKEN_QUERY_PARAMETER, apiKey);
    }

}
```

The token will now be attached to every request that is issued by the WebClient.

Comment: Neat, but does not work well if supplying a uri using `webClient.get().uri(...)` for example. In that case the uriBuilderFactory supplied here is not used at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way, without custom UriBuilderFactory:

```
        this.client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url)
            .filter((request, next) -> {
                URI reqUri = request.url()
                URI newUri = new URI(reqUri.getScheme()
                                , reqUri.getAuthority(), reqUri.getPath()
                                , reqUri.getQuery() + "&key=${apiKey}"
                                , null)
                ClientRequest filtered = ClientRequest.from(request)
                    .url(newUri)
                    .build()
                next.exchange(filtered)
            }).build();
    }
```

This is groovy code but you get the gist, I am sure.

Comment: Just ignore the last curly bracket, copy/paste error :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found a solution with a uriBuilderFactory override.

Firstly we need an additional class:

```
public class QueryParamsUriBuilderFactory extends DefaultUriBuilderFactory {

    private final MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams;

    public QueryParamsUriBuilderFactory(String baseUrl, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
        super(baseUrl);
        this.queryParams = queryParams;
    }

    @Override
    public UriBuilder builder() {
        return super.builder().queryParams(queryParams);
    }

}
```

The next step is to update a configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class IConnectionConfiguration {

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(UriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactoryWithAuthenticationToken) {
        return WebClient.builder()
            .uriBuilderFactory(uriBuilderFactoryWithAuthenticationToken)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactoryWithAuthenticationToken() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> tokenQueryParam = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        tokenQueryParam.add("token", apiKey);

        return new QueryParamsUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl, tokenQueryParam);
    }

}
```

Now it will automatically add token query param if we use `uri(Function<UriBuilder, URI> var1)` function to setup uri. Unfortunately it does not work for `uri(URI var1)` but we can override all methods related to uri in our new `QueryParamsUriBuilderFactory` to fix it for all possible methods for uri setup.